Condense multiple similar alias
I have been working on creating new alias to use at work and noticed my .csh file filling with similar alias that go to different sub-directories but everything else is the same. I am newer at terminal alias and commands, and I was wondering if it was possible to create a catchall that can take the input and apply it to the alias as well as the directory?
Example:
alias ab1 "cd /home/drive/folder1/text/items && ll"
alias ab2 "cd /home/drive/folder2/text/items && ll"
alias ab3 "cd /home/drive/folder3/text/items && ll"

I was wanting to see if it was possible to have something like
alias ab* "cd /home/drive/folder*/text/items && ll"

And when I input ab2 it would auto fill the folder* directory to folder2.
When I use them, they are each run independently and very rarely run at the same time. I tried looking it up but was unsure on how to word it to correctly articulate my intention through search. Thank you ahead of time for any input.

Unlike the majority of shells (where you'd want to use a shell function for this kind of thing), the C shell supports parameterization of aliases:
~/dir> alias ab "echo /home/drive/\!:1/text/items"
~/dir> ab foo
/home/drive/foo/text/items
~/dir> ab bar
/home/drive/bar/text/items
~/dir>

So you should be able to do
alias ab "cd /home/drive/folder\!:1/text/items && ll"

then
ab 1
ab 2

etc.
See for example

The C Shell - Arguments to aliases

